# Block already defined error in beamer

Tags: beamer, block

I making presentation through beamer. I want to use blocks as given below but getting error. See the code given below:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 %\usetheme{Boadilla}
   \usetheme{Madrid}
 \usepackage{bibentry}
  \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

   \usepackage{graphicx}

     \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \newcommand{\block}[2]{%
   \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \boxed{\mathstrut #1}\\
    \scriptstyle\blockleftarrowfill\,#2\,\blockrightarrowfill
   \end{array}%
 }
  \newcommand{\blockleftarrowfill}{%
   \mathord\leftarrow
    \mkern -7mu
   \cleaders\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern -2mu\smash-\mkern -2mu$}\hfill
 \mkern -7mu\smash-%
   }
   \newcommand{\blockrightarrowfill}{%
    \smash-%
   \mkern -7mu
    \cleaders\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern -2mu\smash-\mkern -2mu$}\hfill
    \mkern -7mu
    \mathord\rightarrow
       }


      \begin{document}

              \[
           g = \block{\ g_1^{\epsilon_1(g)} \cdots\  
         g_l^{\epsilon_l(g)}\ } 
            {l}\quad
          \block{g_{l+1}^{\epsilon_{l+1}(g)} \cdots 
                  g_{2l}^{\epsilon_{2l}(g)}}{l}\quad
                \cdots\quad
        \block{g_{r}(g)^{\epsilon_{r}(g)}\cdots 
              g_k^{\epsilon_k(g)}\quad}{l}
               \]



            \end{document}
```

**Question :** Block already defined error is comming. How to correct it?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\block}[2]{%` instead of `\newcommand{\block}[2]{%` works for me.

Comment: or `\newcommand{\myblock}`. The problem is that `block` is an existing command in beamer, therefore it is not allowed to define it using `\newcommand` but you can renew it or choose a different name.

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @samcarter there is surely some duplicate containing newcommand vs. renewcommand, better to close it after finding the most suitable duplicate.

Comment: @Marijn These duplicates focus on redefining the command, whereas your comment also suggests to choose a different name, which is imho the much better solution.